# Want to put some seconds delay in calling a function

Tags: ajax, function, call, delay, seconds

I want to put some seconds delay in calling a function, so that the user don't spam by clicking rapidly on like button and my ajax call successfully executed at the background.

**Reason of doing so:** (Because i am doing calculations on this click in ajax file. So if a user clicks rapidly , it disturbs the count.)

**Effect after click the button:** The like button changes to unlike button

Here is my Jquery Code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function like(post_id,post_user_id,user_id)
{
    var last_msg_id         = $('.load_more').attr("id");
        $.post('ajax_files/like.php', {post_id:post_id,post_user_id:post_user_id,user_id:user_id},
        function(data) 
        {
            $("#extra_small_loader_"+post_id).empty().html('<img src="images/extra_small_loader.gif">');            




            if(last_msg_id!='end')
            {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "ajax_files/maintain_posts.php",
                    data: "lastmsg="+ last_msg_id, 
                    beforeSend:  function() 
                        {
                        $('a.load_more').html('<img src="load_more_script/loading.gif" />');

                        },
                    success: function(html)
                        {
                        $("#reload_posts").html(html);
                        }
                });
            }



        });
}
</script>
```

And here is my HTML for **LIKE** Button:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="like(<?php echo $ps->id; ?>,<?php echo $ps->user_id; ?>,<?php echo $user_id; ?>)">

  <span class="Icon_Text_Font">Like</span>

</a>
```

And here is my Code for **UNLIKE** Button:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="unlike(<?php echo $ps->id; ?>,<?php echo $ps->user_id; ?>,<?php echo $user_id; ?>)">

  <span class="Icon_Text_Font">Unlike</span>

</a>
```

Comment: In the beforeSend you could disable button, and in the succes (or on error) yopu could enable the button

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use setTimeout()

eg.

```
setTimeout(function() { functionName() },5000);
```